# How to use co-ordinates from a Features collection to find centroid of a polygon?

Tags: javascript, arrays, polygon, centroid, turfjs

So I want to find the centre of a polygon using turf, by the following method:

```
     var polygon = turf.polygon([[[-81, 41], [-88, 36], [-84, 31], [-80, 33], [-77, 39], [-81, 41]]]);

     var centroid = turf.centroid(polygon);

     //addToMap
     var addToMap = [polygon, centroid]
```

However, instead of the above co-ordinates, the co-ordinates I want to use are embedded in an array in a Features Collection. The collection looks as follows:

```
     const IsleOfManPolygon = 

     {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",

     "name": "Isle of Man",

     "crs": { "type": "name", "properties":},
     "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties", "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon",    "coordinates": [ -4.49169921875, 54.343505859375 ], [ -4.49102783203125, 54.343872070312443 ], [ -4.490112304687443, 54.3441162109375 ]]
     }
     ;
```

I have omitted most of the co-ordinates, there are are hundreds of them! How do I get the array of polygon co-ordinates in the Features Collection so I can use them to work out the centroid of the polygon? Is there a way to reference the features collection co-ordinate array so I don't have to input them manually?

Comment: have you tried already available packages ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/centroid

Comment: btw, you are probably looking for `centerOfMass`